# In BitcoinJ, what is the purpose of Peer?

Tags: bitcoinj

In BitcoinJ, there is [`PeerGroup`](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/source/browse/core/src/main/java/com/google/bitcoin/core/PeerGroup.java) and [`Peer`](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/source/browse/core/src/main/java/com/google/bitcoin/core/Peer.java).

I understand there are differences such as one is related to a group of peers while other is related to a single peer.

When should I use which construct? Are both necessary?

From the code, it seems that we should only be interested in `PeerGroup` and not `Peer`. Then whats the purpose of `Peer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When should I use which construct?

Use PeerGroup, unless you want to connect to a specific Bitcoin node.

> From the code, it seems that we should only be interested in `PeerGroup` and not `Peer`.

`PeerGroup` will construct `Peer` objects. It's necessary, even if you don't use it directly.